# Nodejs application run without port

Tags: node.js, port

I've developed a few Node.js programs that operate on various ports.

Is there a way to use the paths `http://localhost/node1` and `http://localhost/node2` to run without port access?

Answer (score 2):

If you want your app to be **accessible over http** protocol then your **app needs to listen on a port**.

If you just want to avoid using port when you type the url in the browser you need your app to listen on **port 80** which is **used by browser as default** so can be omitted.